# Optimizing S3 image file access for image processing, within a Django app

Tags: django, caching, image-processing, file-io, amazon-s3

For the django apps I typically build, S3 is a no-brainer for storing any non-trivial static data... most notably images. It makes page loads much faster than I could otherwise. I use the S3BotoStorage filesystem backend in the [django-storages package](https://bitbucket.org/david/django-storages/wiki/Home) and I have found it to be fantastically transparent and hassle-free w/r/t implementation.

Not so much w/r/t operation, though: now, I'm building out a small family of apps, which all depend on a Django-centric image-processing platform. Most of the processor-bound operations I'm doing can either be handled within an HTTP request lifecycle; for the few processes that are more demanding, I use an async signal queue and a RESTful API to defuse potential bottlenecks through timing and UI considerations.

That's all great, when working with image data local to the processing app. S3 throws a monkey wrench into it by making all file-object operations totally nondeterministic. The problem isn't failures (I get a random IOError or somesuch from inside the django-storages app maybe once a week), but the time it takes to access files, and the total lack of any sort of filesystem cache.

I've done a bit of refactoring to support S3 -- scrubbing all absolute paths out of the codebase; implementing retries and workarounds for uncoöperative Boto requests -- my impetus for building out the signal queue, in fact, was in order to mitigate the S3 file-access overhead (the details of which I will spare you). The point is that if I'm supporting S3, I'd like to support it in the most awesome/productive way possible.

Naturally, I don't want to screw things up or complicate things further by putting in the kind of caching layer that will take babysitting -- I'm after a straightforward (and preferably uncomplicated) way to speed up the file-object operations I'm performing on S3 images. For example, if I read from a given file object several times within a reasonable timeframe, it'd be great if the subsequent reads were cached enough so that each read didn't have to fetch the file anew from S3.

Does anyone have a module recommendation, a sample implementation, a configuration tactic, or any combo of the above, with which I might address my S3 file-op woes?

Comment: Just wondering what you came up with to address the time-to-access issue. I have a similar situation where I'm using Django+S3 to store files, but have some server-side processing tasks requiring access to the files.

Comment: @Fiver At this point, I am trying to move as much of the image-processing stuff to the client, using the canvas element API and web-workers – that sort of thing wasn’t as feasable when the question was written as it is now, yes.